# Update rows and then select the updated rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysqli, sql-update

I have a mysqli query that updates rows in my table. I am aware of the `mysqli::$affected_rows` method however all that returns is the number of rows that were affected.

How do I return the affected rows without doing another query and selecting them using the same `WHERE` operator?

Comment: There is no other way to achieve it,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return updated rows. You still need to perform a `SELECT` query.

If your `WHERE` condition is very difficult and you do not want to perform it twice, then maybe it will be more efficient to add additional column `update_key`. And each time when you update rows, put a unique value into this column. So, several rows that were updated together have the same value in `update_key`. Then you can select updated rows with `WHERE` that contains only this column.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If you're going to downvote something, it is a good idea to explain why. That we we learn what you're thinking, and we get a chance to disagree with you if we don't agree.

Comment: @DMac, thank you for this comment! I am also very interested why this answer was downvoted at first.